# Html used in your view.aspx

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

Im not quite sure. I have a table that consists of 2 foreach loops(2 reports)
and renders each row in a `<tr>`

Between the reports' data I want to insert an open row to split the data, easier to read,
I inserted an empty `<tr>` but this does not seem to work. I also tried `</ br>` and get a warning.

I know plain html with php..does this differ?

my view.aspx

```
  <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Report/Report.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<TradeUK.Entities.Reporting.KPIResults>>" %>

 <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
     TradeUK KPI Searches Data
 </asp:Content>

 <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

 <h2>TradeUK KPI Searches Data</h2>

<p>
<%: Html.ActionLink("Export as CSV...", "TradeUKKPIDataExport", "Report", new { @date = ViewBag.jobSortedReportDate}, null )%>    
</p>

<table>
<tr>
    <th style="width: 400px;">
        Title
    </th>
    <th style="width: 150px;">
        Total
    </th>
    <th style="width: 150px;">
        Week 6
    </th>
    <th style="width: 150px;">
        Week 5
    </th>
    <th style="width: 150px;">
        Week 4
    </th>
    <th style="width: 150px;">
        Week 3
    </th>
    <th style="width: 150px;">
        Week 2
    </th>
    <th style="width: 150px;">
        Week 1
    </th>
</tr>

<% foreach (var item in Model)
  {
%>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <%: item.Title%>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%: item.Total%>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%: item.Week6%>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%: item.Week5%>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%: item.Week4%>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%: item.Week3%>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%: item.Week2%>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%: item.Week1%>
    </td>
</tr>  

<%} %>

<tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr>    
<tr>
    <th style="width: 400px;">
        Title
    </th>
    <th style="width: 150px;">
        Total
    </th>
    <th style="width: 150px;">
        Week 6
    </th>
    <th style="width: 150px;">
        Week 5
    </th>
    <th style="width: 150px;">
        Week 4
    </th>
    <th style="width: 150px;">
        Week 3
    </th>
    <th style="width: 150px;">
        Week 2
    </th>
    <th style="width: 150px;">
        Week 1
    </th>
</tr>

<% foreach (var item2 in ViewBag.jobSortedModel)
{
%>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <%: item2.Title %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%: item2.Total %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%: item2.Week6 %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%: item2.Week5 %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%: item2.Week4 %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%: item2.Week3 %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%: item2.Week2 %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%: item2.Week1 %>
    </td>
</tr>  
<% 
  } %>

 </table>
 </asp:Content>
```

I dont quite understand?

Comment: Just a note: it is `<br />`, not `</ br>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

instead of `<tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr>` use `<tr><td colspan="8">&nbsp;</td></tr>` and you can set some style to this td, for making some more vertical space, like `<tr><td colspan="8" style="height:2em;">&nbsp;</td></tr>`

Comment: adding a <tr> should work? That is how i used to do it or is it different now because you are working in a asp.net env.?

Comment: At the end of the day it will be all outputted in HTML to the client.